# How to make a blur effect over a shape in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an shape with blur background like this:

[image: Blur Effect]

I want to put in on my layout without having to cut it from the PSD file. And I have tried to use CSS to create it but what I have got till now is just a shape with a solid background. Any answers from any superman would be highly appreciated! Thank you very much,!

These are my code until now:

```css
.sld-shadow {
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 96px solid transparent;
  border-right: 96px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 36px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="sld-shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS filters:

```
.sld-shadow {
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

You'll want to make sure that you have [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works but the shape is still not same as the image above. I have no idea what to do next. Could you give me an solution?

Comment: Well it looks like there is a gradient built in, so you could use [gradient borders](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) to get it closer but at that point you're sacrificing a lot of browser compatibility. It'd probably to just take it from the PSD.